# How to know if your sms filter extension is enable in iOS settings?

Tags: ios, swift, settings

When we add an extension to our application for example by filtering SMS

Add extension:

[image]

After launching our application on the device (hereinafter referred to as the host app), we need to activate our extension in the iOS settings in the message section:

Enable extension:

[image]

How in the host app to know the status of the extension, is it active in the settings or not?

I need to know the state in order to ask the user to activate the extension or not to ask the user to activate the extension, and instead show other content in the host app

Comment: Looking for the same kind of API to test. It is really difficult to test the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,There is no API to check SMS filter extension is enabled in containing app or not.

Comment: But for call extension iOS has API

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow it and I don't think they will do it even in the future.

Here is what they say in the IdentityLookup documentation

> Also for privacy reasons, your app extension ***cannot write data*** to containers shared with the containing app.